# Python Selenium; how to locate a html form in a frame without the needed locator?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

so I have trouble editing a HTML form in a frame because there is no type="text" or input locater.

The form looks like this:

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7qK1.png)

The HTML code looks like this:

[HTML Code, pic of the Code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMjC4.png)

```
<h2 class="reqd">
   <strong>Artikelbeschreibung</strong><a role="button" href="javascript:;" aria-label="Hilfe - Artikelbeschreibung" class="bh" fn="bh"></a>
   <div class="edp-ly edp-abs" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" aria-label="Beschreiben Sie den zu verkaufenden Artikel vollständig und genau. Gestalten Sie die Beschreibung möglichst klar und kurz, damit sie auch auf Mobilgeräten lesbar ist. Mehr erfahren" id="editpane_description_toolTip"><i class="edp-pl"></i><a tabindex="-1" fn="hid" class="clo" href="javascript:;" aria-label="Schließen"></a>Beschreiben Sie den zu verkaufenden Artikel vollständig und genau. Gestalten Sie die Beschreibung möglichst klar und kurz, damit sie auch auf Mobilgeräten lesbar ist. <a href="https://pages.ebay.de/help/sell/title_desc_ov.html#inform" target="_blank" tabindex="-1">Mehr erfahren</a></div>
</h2>
<div id="editpane_desc">
   <div class="err-lbl mr-b3"></div>
   <div>
      <div>
         <div id="descDiv" class="eidesc-wrap-ad">
            <div id="em_description"></div>
            <input type="hidden" value="false" id="httpsErr">
            <div id="dv_wrapper">
               <div></div>
            </div>
            <div id="rteDiv">
               <div id="v4-126" class="rt tab rt-std">
                  <span><span class="lnk-wr"></span><span class="lnk-wr" id="v4-126_switchLnk"><a href="javascript:;" role="tab" aria-label="Standard" class="htm-lnk  sel " aria-selected="true">Standard</a><a href="javascript:;" role="tab" aria-label="HTML" class="std-lnk">HTML</a></span><span class="mo-prv"><a href="javascript:;" role="button" aria-label="Mobiloptimierung testen" id="v4-126_moprv" fn="mob-prv">Mobiloptimierung testen</a></span></span>
                  <div id="v4-126txtEdit_ht_wr" class="htm">
                     <div class="tts">Einzelheiten unten eingeben (unformatierter Text oder HTML)</div>
                     <iframe id="v4-126txtEdit_ht" name="v4-126txtEdit_ht" title="HTML" aria-describedby="err_ editpane_description_toolTip" style="height:390px" class="ifrm" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                  </div>
                  <div id="v4-126txtEdit_st_wr" class="std">
                     <div id="v4-126_innwrp" class="rt-basic tts">
                        <span class="rt-in">
                           <span class="combo-med">
                              <select id="bear_inserts" title="Vorlagenbezeichnung">
                                 <option>Individuelle Vorlage einfügen</option>
                                 <option fn="cr">Vorlage erstellen</option>
                                 <option fn="mn">Vorlagen verwalten</option>
                              </select>
                           </span>
                           <i></i>
                        </span>
                        <div class="fl">
                           <label class="g-hdn" for="v4-126_fn">Font name</label>
                           <span class="combo-med ff">
                              <select fn="fontname" class="fl" id="v4-126_fn">
                                 <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
                                 <option value="Arial Black">Arial Black</option>
                                 <option value="Comic Sans MS">Comic Sans MS</option>
                                 <option value="Courier">Courier</option>
                                 <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                                 <option value="Impact">Impact</option>
                                 <option value="MS Sans Serif">MS Sans Serif</option>
                                 <option value="Tahoma">Tahoma</option>
                                 <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
                                 <option value="Trebuchet MS">Trebuchet MS</option>
                                 <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
                                 <option value="Western">Western</option>
                              </select>
                           </span>
                           <span id="v4-127" class="fl"></span><label class="g-hdn" for="v4-126_fs">Font size</label>
                           <span class="combo-med fs">
                              <select fs="fontsize" class="fl" id="v4-126_fs">
                                 <option value="1">8</option>
                                 <option value="2">10</option>
                                 <option value="3">12</option>
                                 <option value="4">14</option>
                                 <option value="5">18</option>
                                 <option value="6">24</option>
                                 <option value="7">36</option>
                              </select>
                           </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="fl"><a role="button" href="javascript:;" id="v4-128" title="Font Color" class="col" unselectable="on"></a></div>
                        <div id="v4-126_awr" class="fl"><a href="javascript:;" name="Bold" role="button" title="Bold" id="v4-126_bld" class="bo"></a><a href="javascript:;" name="Italic" role="button" title="Italic" id="v4-126_itc" class="it"></a><a href="javascript:;" name="Underline" role="button" title="Underline" id="v4-126_und" class="ul"></a><a href="javascript:;" name="JustifyLeft" role="button" title="Align Left" id="v4-126_jl" class="jl jlS"></a><a href="javascript:;" name="JustifyCenter" role="button" title="Center" id="v4-126_jc" class="jc"></a><a href="javascript:;" name="JustifyRight" role="button" title="Align Right" id="v4-126_jr" class="jr"></a><a href="javascript:;" name="insertorderedlist" role="button" title="Numbering" id="v4-126_ol" class="ol"></a><a href="javascript:;" name="insertunorderedlist" role="button" title="Bullets" id="v4-126_ul" class="uol"></a><a href="javascript:;" name="outdent" role="button" title="Decrease Indent" id="v4-126_ind" class="oud"></a><a href="javascript:;" name="indent" role="button" title="Increase Indent" id="v4-126_oud" class="ind"></a></div>
                        <a href="javascript:;" role="button" aria-label="Erweiterte Bearbeitung" id="v4-126_advLnk" class="adv fr">Erweiterte Bearbeitung</a>
                        <div class="cl"></div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="ifrmc"><iframe id="v4-126txtEdit_st" name="v4-126txtEdit_st" title="Standard" aria-describedby="err_ editpane_description_toolTip" style="height:362px" class="ifrm" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
                     <input value="<font rwr=&quot;1&quot; style=&quot;font-family:Arial&quot; size=&quot;4&quot;>Test<br></font>" id="description" name="description" type="hidden" md="dt|STRING||em|Bitte geben Sie eine Beschreibung ein.||gdn|description" vld="0">
                  </div>
                  <input id="v4-126_CurrTabId" type="hidden" value="1"><a id="v4-126_nxt_acc_elm" href="javascript:" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Ende: Rich-Text-Editor"></a>
               </div>
               <input name="SemiRestrictedItem" id="SemiRestrictedItem" type="hidden" value="false">
            </div>
        <div class="eidesc-clear"></div>
     </div>
     <input type="hidden" value="0" name="rteMode" id="rteMode">
  </div>
```

and what I want is to change the Text "test" in an other e.g. Sawa

this code is not working, there is no input where I can locate the text I guess.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[class='ifrm']")))
            WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body input"))).send_keys("Sawa")
```

Maybe you guys have an idea?

Cheers

Edit: I uploaded a copy of the site without the creditials but there is no access to the Form I use because it is in javascript.
https://www.file-upload.net/download-14877349/Angeboterstellen.htm.html

it may help

Comment: can you share a link to that page?

Comment: Unfortunatly I can´t I would have to share log in and password for you to see that page and I can´t do this :) Maybe it helps to paste some more HTML code?

Comment: Maybe. Ideally we do would like a link to try running some selenium code, to make some debugging.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). You may like to consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Maybe you are able to rebuild a minimal example on a website with common access? So we can make use of @Prophet s suggestion.

Comment: Hi guys, I´m on it. formatted the HTML and added it as a code and let´s see if I can figure it out and save the site somehow.

Comment: element on screenshot looks like a `textarea`. Did you try to handle this node? You might need to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51230824/send-keys-to-text-area-not-working-using-selenium-in-python